# How to change a string in the vim editor?

Tags: vim, replace, find

I am trying to replace a string with slashes in vim editor

ex: `foo to abc/def/foo`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The title and the content of your question don't match.

`:help pattern` and `:help :substitute` are a bit overwhelming but *very* useful as regular expressions are at the heart of Vim.

[Vim regular Expressions 101](http://vimregex.com/) is a more concise resource.

Anyway, given the following sample text:

```
bar baz foo baz bar
```

your goal can be achieved in a variety of ways. Here are some of them:

```
:s/foo/\/abc\/def\/foo
:s/foo/\/abc\/def\/&
:s+foo+/abc/def/&
```

A few notes:

- In the replacement part, `&` stands for "the matched text". If the match is `foo`, `&` is `foo`. Of course there's not much benefit in using `&` over `foo`, here, but wait until you have a more complex pattern…
- Because Slashes are used to separate the search part and the replace part, you need to escape the actual slashes in both parts for your substitution to work.
- You can use many other symbols instead of slashes to separate the search and the replace parts. This is *very* useful when you know you'll need to escape too many slashes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I changed the question. I did not realize I had that title on. and I was able to replace the string thanks

Comment: @romainl If the answer worked for you, please "Accept" it so it gets a green tick :) It's a way of letting other users see which answer solved it for you, which is useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

To do a string replace in vim you must first be out of visual or insert mode.  Then type ':' to get to execute a vim command.  The substitution command in vim starts with '%s'.  Putting everything together you have

```
:%s/thingyouhave/thingyouwant/
```

In your stated example you need to escape the '/' in your file name with back slashes '\'.

```
:%s/foo/abc\/def\/foo/
```

One other useful bit is putting 'gc' at the end of your expression; this will prompt you for verification before executing each change.  This is useful if you want to change some of the instances of an expression or are unsure if what you are doing is correct.

```
:%s/foo/abc\/def\/foo/gc
```

Comment: There are a lot of errors, here. `:s//` is not a "regular expression": it could be called "substitution" as `:s` is a shorthand for the `:substitute` Ex command. One *may* use regular expressions in the "pattern" part but it is not mandatory (`foo` is technically a regular expressions but… oh well). Substitutions only start with `%s` when you want to apply them to the whole buffer; applied on a single line it's simply `:s`.

Comment: ...it's worth adding too that `c` at the end means to prompt for verification.  The `g` means "do every occurrence on the line," without `g` only the first match gets replaced.  You can use `g` and `c` without one another.