# Vim regular expression find and replace

Tags: linux, vim

I have to find words which are having this pattern:

```
File{some numeric characters}=
```

Example: `File1=`, `File234=`, `File3456=` and delete them.

This is the line:

```
File1=/media/sda5/
```

now I have to replace this line with:

```
/media/sda5/
```

Since I am new to vim, So if anyone can help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a string in the vim editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355809/how-to-change-a-string-in-the-vim-editor)

Comment: `:%s/^File1=\(/media/sda5\)/\1/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command should do what you want:

```
:%s/File\d\+=//g

:%s/         perform substitution on each line in the buffer
File\d\+=    matches 'File' followed by one or more digits until the first '='
//           deletes the matched text
g            do that on every match on the line
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks.
Can you please suggest some good vim reference docs.

Comment: [Vim Regular Expressions 101](http://vimregex.com/) is a classic. See `:help pattern` in Vim for the real reference.